# Fire off SharePoint search from a page without a search box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have the below requirement from a customer. I know I can do it with custom code, but I would prefer to do it with OOTB components if possible. Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

The client wants to have a page with images on it describing their process for the client life cycle, when a user clicks on an image, it should effectively do a search and show the results below the images. So in my head, each image will fire off a search with specific keywords which will then be displayed in a search results container.

I have been scratching around with the search components that are available and just can't seem to get it right.

Comment: You can write a custom code to show search results, or you can pass a value to the `k=` (keyword) url parameter and use core results web part. But the second way you'll still need to write code, so the best practice here is to write custom KeywordQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use SPServices / Jquery to meet the requirement - here is a starter for it querying search: 
http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/example-of-using-the-spservices-search-web-service/

Then you don't need deployable code but you have to create your individual presentation logic for the search results.